# How to find unique patterns in log file via splunk sdk

Tags: java, splunk, splunk-query

I have a requirement to identify all unique log patterns from splunk. I can get it on Patterns on pattern tab on splunk UI, but want to get it programmatically.

I can get search results using splunk sdk, not able to find unique log patterns.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on patterns, it does a [cluster](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Cluster) command. In fact, you can see the cluster command by looking in the activity drop down at jobs that you ran.

It uses [loadjob](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Loadjob) on the search you just ran, and adds this:

```
| cluster t=0.9 labelonly=true labelfield=_patterns match=termset
| findkeywords labelfield=_patterns dedup=true
```

So this is just a regular search, and then using cluster.